# Docker compose secrets

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-secrets

The newer `docker compose` (vs `docker-compose`) allows you to set `secrets` in the `build` section.  This is nice because if you do secrets at runtime then the file is readable by anyone that can get into the container by reading `/run/secrets/<my_secret>`.

Unfortunately, it appears that it's only possible to pass the secrets via either the environment or a file.  Doing it via the environment doesn't seem like a great idea because someone on the box could read the `/proc/<pid>/environment` while the image is being built to snag the secrets.  Doing it via a file on disk isn't good because then the secret is being stored on disk unencrypted.

It seems like the best way to do this would be with something like

```
docker swarm init 
$(read -sp "Enter your secret: "; echo $REPLY) | docker secret create my_secret -
docker compose build --no-cache
docker swarm leave --force
```

Alas, it appears that Docker can't read from the swarm for build time secrets for some unknown reason.

What is the best way to do this? This seems to be a slight oversight, along the lines of docker secrete create not having a way to prompt for the value instead of having to resort to to hacks like above to keep the secret out of your bash history.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: This is for SWARM/Remote docker systems, not targeted on local build time secrets. (I realised you were asking for those primarily and just mentioned swarm in the second part of the question. I believe it still holds good advice for some so ill leave the answer undeleted.

Docker Swarm can only read runtime-based secrets you create with the docker secret create command and must already exist on the cluster when deploying stack. We had been in the same situation before. We solved the "issue" using docker contexts. You can create an SSH-based docker context which points to a manager (we just use the first one). Then on your LOCAL device (we use Win as the base platform and WSL2/Linux VM for the UNIX part), you can simply run docker commands with inline --context property. More on context on [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/). For instance: docker --context production secret create .... And so on.

Comment: And the best part is all the "secret history". (Files on disk, envs, commands, ...) are actually stored on your VM/WSL2 machine, and can simply be .. well .. "cleaned" when needed. The downside is that you are now even more responsible for keeping the information secure.